# SQL - Renaming fields after query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im Running into walls with this one but im sure somebody here knows a way around

I have 2 tables for example `USERS` and `ISSUES`. In USERS they have we say 2 columns needed

- id
- firstname
- lastname

in 'ISSUES` they have 2 columns needed

- id
- assigned_to_id

Im trying to compare and replace a field on output. 
for example `if users.id = issues.assigned_to_id` 
then print 'users.firstname`instead of`users.id`

Any help would be fantastic. cheers guys.

EDIT; i can do two queries to what i need, the first one is this;

```
SELECT assigned_to_id AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Issues FROM issues
WHERE `status_id`=1 
OR `status_id`=2 
OR `status_id`=4
OR `status_id`=7 
OR `status_id`=8 
OR `status_id`=9 
OR `status_id`=10
GROUP BY `assigned_to_id`
```

and this one;

```
SELECT id, firstname FROM users
```

now if users.id = issues.assigned_to_id basically use the corresponding users firstname instead of the id

Comment: I can't understand this question. Can you please provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Why does "issues" have a "firstname" column?  Why would you ever want to print the user id instead of the user name?  Why can't you returns the actual data and let your application logic manage the display?  It's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I need to compare the two fields, id and assigned_to_id. if they are the same, then instead of writing out the id number, display the firstname of that id. i hope this helps

Comment: @Finchie: Just do an Inner JOIN between the 2 tables... and SELECT firstname ... 
THAT's IT !

Comment: @SanRyu iv tried that, but no success. iv used this; SELECT users.firstname AS Name FROM users INNER JOIN issues ON users.id = issues.assigned_to_id

Comment: I don't know then ... sorry !

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issues.firstName column in your example so I assume you mean users.firstname

So to put into plain English what your after...

You want to return all issues and when an issue matches a user return the user name instead of the issueID?

If so then this should do it (Changed left to right as you wanted all issues I believe)

```
SELECT coalesce(u.FirstName, to_char(I.ID)) as UserNameOrIssueID
FROM Users U
RIGHT JOIN issues I 
 on U.ID = I.assigned_to_ID
```

The tricky part here is that firstname and ID are likely of different data types, so you have to cast the user.id to a character field in the DB appropriate syntax...

Using explicit cast (I'm also assuming Issue.ID is a numeric field if it's character then the second one below will work fine as it doesn't even need to do the implicit conversion.

```
SELECT coalesce(u.FirstName, cast(I.ID as char(30)) as UserNameOrIssueID
FROM Users U
RIGHT JOIN issues I 
 on U.ID = I.assigned_to_ID
```

Hoping implicit works:

```
SELECT coalesce(u.FirstName, I.ID) as UserNameOrIssueID
FROM Users U
RIGHT JOIN issues I 
 on U.ID = I.assigned_to_ID
```

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Updated to a right join and confirmed to_char syntax for this RDBMS.

Comment: YES!!! in plain english thats what i need (except the "otherwise return the issueID" part :)

Comment: I think what I have should do that then.  (updated response) The join returns all issues and only those from users that match.  A coalesce seems to be easier to read here than the case.  coalesce returns the first non-null value in a series.  So in this situation when firstname is null due to no matching values found, issue.id will be returned.

Comment: I have tried that also to no avail. the issue i seem to be having now is the to_char function does not exist. btw thanks for the help so far i really appreciate it

Comment: Well, I'll try an explict cast as well as an IMPLICIT cast and hope, but I don't think the implicit will work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if this is what you need:

```
select 
  u.firstname
from 
  users as u,
  issues as i
where 
  u.id = i.assigned_to_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that ... Only if you Alter table issues...
all you can do is this !

```
SELECT U.firstname FROM USERS U
LEFT JOIN ISSUES I ON U.id = I.assigned_to_id
```

I'll pus an update later ... with the alter table ! Stay tune !

**UPDATE**

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTable

SELECT U.firstname INTO #TempTable FROM USERS U
LEFT JOIN ISSUES I ON U.id = I.assigned_to_id

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

-- ALTER TABLE ISSUES ADD firstname varchar(100) -- RUN ONLY ONCE !

UPDATE I 
SET firstname = (SELECT TOP 1 U.firstname FROM USERS U
                    LEFT JOIN ISSUES I ON U.id = I.assigned_to_id)
    FROM ISSUES I

SELECT * FROM ISSUES
```

Comment: thanks for this, i just added sample code to show you in more detail what i mean :)

Comment: Just use 
SELECT U.firstname AS Name FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN ISSUES I ON U.id = I.assigned_to_id

I don't see the problem !

Comment: so from my code, this would be what you are suggesting? SELECT users.firstname AS Name FROM users INNER JOIN issues ON users.id = issues.assigned_to_id

Comment: Yes ... the inner join return the rows that are strictly referenced from a table to another... no NULL's are involved !

Comment: FYI: OP is using mysql not sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look over the weekend, this is what worked and did what i needed it to do. thanks for your help guys.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Issues, assigned_to_id as UserID , users.firstname as Name FROM issues
JOIN users on users.id = issues.assigned_to_id
WHERE `status_id`=1 
OR `status_id`=2 
OR `status_id`=4
OR `status_id`=7 
OR `status_id`=8 
OR `status_id`=9 
OR `status_id`=10
GROUP BY `assigned_to_id`
ORDER BY Issues DESC
```